# Convert CSV values in Column into separate columns with binary answers

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have some data that looks like this

```
ColumnName
value 1, value 2
value 1, value 3
```

I would like to eliminate this column, and instead replace with with a column for each value, like so.

```
value 1 value 2 value 3
1       1       0
1       0       1
```

Is there a library/function call available to take care of this for me? I have seen in R there is a close equivalent from the splitstackshape library called Csplit_e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnName': ['value 1, value 2', 'value 1, value 3']})


#          ColumnName
# 0  value 1, value 2
# 1  value 1, value 3

pd.get_dummies(df.ColumnName.str.split(',', expand=True), prefix='', prefix_sep='')


#    value 1   value 2   value 3
# 0        1         1         0
# 1        1         0         1
```

I hope this helps.